# BigCommerce and Myob API Integration for products

Tags: api, bigcommerce, myob

We are looking at importing products, skus and inventory from Myob to show on bigcommerce. We have mapped the APIs required. Since we haven't worked on bigcommerce before, we need some guidance on the best way to proceed. Is it better to create this integration like an app or work directly on the core? What are the performance issues, pros and cons in choosing this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, if you're going to continue to sync product data over time, an app may be better. However if this is a single sync to move over all data from Myob to BC, working directly may be better.